# The user could not be added.SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql

I am not using any framework, i am developing myself... and i get that SQL error, the funny part is i get the error and the data/information still gets inserted but that error persists, i set user_id to accept null, then it moved to new_user_email

```
<?php
require_once("../private/initialize.php");
if (!$session->is_logged_in()) { redirect_to("login.php"); }

//if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    //if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        //$email_to = trim($_POST['email_to']);
        /*$user = new User();
        $user->setId($session->user_id);*/
        //print_r($user->getId());

        $invite_user = Invite::invite_by_mail($session->user_id, "rdweb@gmail.com");

        if($invite_user) {
            $invite_user->invite();
            echo "Invite Sent";
        }else{
            echo "Invite Not Sent";
        }
//  }
//}
?>
```

i am setting the logged in user session id to the user_id which i wrote in the Invite class,

```
public static function invite_by_mail($user_id, $email_to="") {
        if(!empty($user_id)) {
        $invite = new Invite();
        $invite->user_id = (int)$user_id;
        $invite->new_user_email = $email_to;
        $invite->token = Invite::generateToken();
        return $invite;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
public function invite()
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO invites (user_id, new_user_email, token, date_invited)
                      VALUES(:user_id, :new_user_email, :token, :date_invited)";
try {
    // prepare sql an d bind parameters
    $core = ConnectionManager::getInstance();
    $stmt = $core->con->prepare($sql);

    $user_id = $this->user_id;
    $new_user_email = $this->new_user_email;
    $token = $this->token;
    $date_invited = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time());

    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':new_user_email', $new_user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':token', $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date_invited', $date_invited, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $this->id = $core->con->lastInsertId();
        echo "New Invite Recorded";
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    //echo "Insert Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    echo "DataBase Error: The user could not be added." . $e->getMessage();
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "General Error: The user could not be added." . $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

i need help

this is the error i get

> DataBase Error: The user could not be added.SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity     constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be nullNew Invite RecordedInvite Sent

and then it tells me invite sent and New invite added and populates the table

when i make sure the user_id table accepts Null from database, it the moves to new_user_email hence the error is now

> DataBase Error: The user could not be added.SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity     constraint violation: 1048 Column 'new_user_email' cannot be nullNew Invite RecordedInvite Sent
>   [Invite Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCTyO.jpg)

Comment: `$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);` Please dump out the value of `$user_id` here, as it appears it's not set when it should be

Comment: Have you taken the time to do any basic debugging?

Comment: @Dezza , how is it not set, i was setting it with User session id stored when the user is logged in to know what particular user sent the invite

Comment: at the top of each page, [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). Show debugging info to the people you seek help from. Like var_dump's

Comment: @Drew please correct me if i am wrong, but i don't seem to get what you are talking about... this data inserts in my database... i just don't know why its complaining about integrity constraint violation, please if there is something i am missing please show it.. we are here to help each other

Comment: can you create a minimal complete verifiable example (schema and data load and all script particles) I don't care where you put it or email it or drop box it. I will verify and try to help

Comment: Ok.. will send you my script... can i send via email? @Drew

Comment: sure my email is in my profile. I upvoted, reopened. Sorry I closed it.

Comment: @Drew.. Hope you got the mail bruv

Comment: looking at it now thx

Comment: If you get an error like that, but the data still goes in, it sounds like you have a trigger that you have forgotten about, and the trigger is throwing the error.  `SHOW TRIGGERS IN database_name;`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot .. there are no triggers... i also did show triggers to reconfirm... but there are none

Comment: It's hard to say, since this obviously is not all of your code, but it appears that they `invite()` function (or at least the same `INSERT` command used by that function) is being called twice. The first time without the values, and the second time with the values.

Comment: @PatrickQ ... where do you think its been called twice... i have looked thru the code again and again... it looks right...

Comment: I can't tell because this isn't all of your code.  But the fact that you are seeing _both_ the error message _and_ your custom success text ("New Invite RecordedInvite Sent") leads me to strongly believe that it is being called twice somehow.

Comment: @PatrickQ Actually Patrick its all my code, i did a self study ... and i built on what i learnt... also i did it and wrote it OOP so i can build gradually my own Framework.. , My other Objects like users and members arent given this error.. just this invite